# In windows form, why are some text in .resx file not displayed correctly in terms of upper/lower case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, resources, resx

I encountered a very unusual Windows form bug and I just thought maybe some of you have an idea or have encountered this before. If so,  please yell. :)

For instance (not exact text)
Excerpt of .resx file (Resource)

```
<data name="Events.Text" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Select one or more RaceCar tracks:</value>
</data>
```

this will display "Select one or more Racecar tracks:" which is incorrect because it should be RaceCar instead of Racecar.

But if I add any extra character at the end, it will be fixed.

```
<data name="Events.Text" xml:space="preserve">
<value>Select one or more RaceCar tracks: </value>   -> if I add space " "
</data>
```

this will now display as is: "Select one or more RaceCar tracks: "

Any insight to what's happening in the .resx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lengthy debugging, turns out, something in our code changes the value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have some caching at play here. Check how the files are referenced. Embedded content, just files in the bin folder etc. Does it update the file if you do a full rebuild of your code? If so it could be that your files are refreshed when rebuilding and cached after you reference them in the app.

Comment: Hi, I have just tried your suggestion. I've cleared all Debug folders, cleaned soln, rebuilt it and run the app again. Still the same result. but Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. :)